# How to fix "in article" links after upgrade

Tags: articles, joomla-1.5, joomla-3.5, weblinks

So... I had to upgrade joomla 1.5 to 3.5 today. It was much fun :D

Managed to fix everything except links to other articles that are embedded in the content.

Site is multilingual.

Here is original link within content from Joomla 1.5 and how it get's rendered on the frontend:

```
index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=80

/en/?id=80
```

And here is link that Joomla 3.5 editor will generate:

```
index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=80&amp;catid=8&amp;lang=en-GB&amp;Itemid=12" hreflang="en"

/en/8-english/80-ester-house-of-stanisic-lu-fi.html
```

**Joomla now requires me to input catid, lang and itemid. Is there a way around this, or some kind of tool that'll fix joomla "in article" links?**

Comment: Can you share the link to your site?  I can take a look to figure out the simplified version...

Answer (score 1):

Generally you need to find a variant of the Joomla 3.5 that will work; usually it is stripping off the SEF, etc to a simplified version. Once you find that, you can adjust your .htaccess to reform the J1.5 version into the simplified J3.5 version.